# Two interactive ListLinePlots

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic, interactive

I need to build an interactive interface to visualize multiples plots at the same time.

Let's consider two lists:

```
a ={{{5.34799, 0.0266045}, {10.696, 0.0335664}, {16.044, 
   0.0375446}, {21.392, 0.0411499}, {26.74, 0.0441336}, {37.4359, 
   0.0484848}, {48.1319, 0.0566899}, {58.8279, 0.086651}, {69.5239, 
   0.145206}}, {{4.64667, 0.0230256}, {9.29334, 0.0311688}, {13.94, 
   0.0404352}, {18.5867, 0.0520884}, {23.2333, 0.064584}, {32.5267, 
   0.0902772}, {41.82, 0.116813}, {51.1133, 0.149666}, {60.4067, 
   0.198526}}, {{5.94141, 0.0234662}, {11.8828, 0.0331042}, {17.8242, 
   0.0448373}, {23.7656, 0.0581069}, {29.707, 0.0723542}, {41.5899, 
   0.102944}, {53.4727, 0.137445}, {65.3555, 0.192479}, {77.2383, 
   0.268325}}};

b ={{{4.40558, 0.0167801}, {8.81116, 0.0228161}, {13.2167, 
   0.03018}, {17.6223, 0.0375439}, {22.0279, 0.0455114}, {30.8391, 
   0.0610843}, {39.6502, 0.0795545}, {48.4614, 0.102129}, {57.2725, 
   0.132913}}, {{5.3193, 0.0241877}, {10.6386, 0.0302957}, {15.9579, 
   0.0362815}, {21.2772, 0.0423895}, {26.5965, 0.048131}, {37.2351, 
   0.060347}, {47.8737, 0.0746398}, {58.5123, 0.0922308}, {69.1509, 
   0.134498}}, {{3.74719, 0.0189235}, {7.49439, 0.0256819}, {11.2416, 
   0.0318259}, {14.9888, 0.0377242}, {18.736, 0.043991}, {26.2304, 
   0.0557875}, {33.7247, 0.0686899}, {41.2191, 0.0818381}, {48.7135, 
   0.0980582}}};
```

Each sublist of a and b has a corresponding f list: a[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO8XF.png)] --> fa1, a[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uth6F.png)] --> fa2 etc..

Let's consider for instance the following f:

```
fa1 = Prime[Range[25]];
fa2 = Log[Range[10, 20]];
fa3 = Prime[Range[5]];

fb1 = Log[Range[5, 20]];
fb2 = Log[Range[30, 60]];
fb3 = Prime[Range[50]];
```

I want to plot  a and b lists, click with my mouse each plotted curve and visualize the corresponding f plotted alongside.

I wrote the following code that I would like to improve.

```
  status = 1; 
    uno = ListLinePlot[{Button[a[[1]], status = 1], 
    Button[a[[2]], status = 2], Button[a[[3]], status = 3], 
    Button[b[[1]], status = 4], Button[b[[2]], status = 5], 
    Button[b[[3]], status = 6]}, PlotStyle -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"curve"}, Below], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

     f = {fa1, fa2, fa3, fb1, fb2, fb3};

     due = Dynamic[Manipulate[ListLinePlot[f[[status]], PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, y}},PlotStyle -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},PlotLabel -> "Function"], {x, 10}, {y, 50}]];

    TableForm[{{uno, due}}]
```

[image]

****In summary, I would like to:**

**1) click on a plot like this one:****

[image]

**3) Highlight the curves that I click;
2) visualize all the f that I click, something like:**

[image]

3. **Obtain an automatic code for hundreds of lists.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by removing the `Dynamic` wrapper around Manipulate. I can't see any reason why you would need it. Then, try replacing your manually created list in `ListLinePlot`, with `MapIndexed[Button[#, status = First@#2] &, Join[a, b]]`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @MarcoB! (: